# Table column count & searching for a value in Python

Tags: python, list, search, count

Let's say I have this multi-dimensional table called "a":

```
[['John',  8, 'Student'   ],
 ['Paul', 22, 'Car Dealer'],
 ['Nick', 30, 'Doctor'    ],
 ['Mark', 66, 'Retired'   ]]
```

---

Is there a built in function in python to count how many columns are there (4) instead of doing something like this?:

```
f = 0
for item in a: f = f + 1
```

also can I have the two above lines combined in one?

---

With a built-in function:

- how can I search in the names, in the first column to find if a name exists?
- how can I search the whole table if a value exists?

Comment: Those are rows not columns.

Comment: What type of values you're going to search in the table?(provide some examples) For name related search convert the list to a dict to get `O(1)` lookup.

Comment: sorry, you're correct they're called rows. -- there are both alphanumeric and numeric. can you post a way to do below?

Comment: Provide some examples related to search so that we can provide you efficient solutions.

Comment: a search example is: does "Nick" exist in the first names column? is a person 50 years old? is there an engineer?

Comment: Use a database then, no python datastructure will be able to do all these things efficiently. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `len` for rows:

```
table=[['John',  8, 'Student'   ],
       ['Paul', 22, 'Car Dealer'],
       ['Nick', 30, 'Doctor', 'this row is longer..','making 5'],
       ['Mark', 66, 'Retired'   ]]

y=len(table)      # 4
```

And then you will have to go row by row to find the max width:

```
x=max(len(row) for row in table)     # 5
```

You can use a list comprehension to get a vertical column's values:

```
>>> [li[0] for li in table]
['John', 'Paul', 'Nick', 'Mark']
```

To find a value, you can use a generator expression with any or just test membership:

```
any('John' in l for l in table)      # True
'Paul' in (li[0] for li in table)    # True
```

To find which row, use a list comprehension:

```
[i for i,l in enumerate(table) if 'Mark' in l]   # 3
```

Comment: thanks. why `any(66 in l for l in table)` returns true while `66 in (li for li in table)` returns false? what's the difference? what's the syntax of the second example I posted here in this comment called?

Comment: `(li for li in table)` just returns a generator over your original table. If you want to see this, type `[li for li in table]==table` in the interpreter. To find 66 specifically, use the field that it is in in the row: `66 in (li[1] for li in table)` or use `any` You can see that these are two different expressions. `any` will return True if '66' is found anywhere in each row. The other expression is specific to a column. (depending on type of course...)

Answer (score 4):

As noted by Paul:

```
len(your_list) # Returns number of rows (which is what I assume you meant)
```

For you other two questions, this is the closest you can get to a built-in:

```
>>> 'Paul' in (row[0] for row in your_list)
True
>>> 66 in itertools.chain.from_iterable(your_list)
True
```

Comment: that's what i was looking for! can you explain me the syntax in the first line of code which returns "True"? where in the doc can i read about it?

Comment: It's a generator expression:http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `len` builtin:

```
f = len(a)
```

Comment: @Nickl `len()` count the number of *elements*, whatever they might be. `a` is a `list` of rows (which happen to be `list`'s themselves).

Answer (score 2):

Use a database to perform all these operations efficiently:

---

**Create and populate the database:**

```
import sqlite3
a = [['John',  8, 'Student'   ],
 ['Paul', 22, 'Car Dealer'],
 ['Nick', 30, 'Doctor'    ],
 ['Mark', 66, 'Retired'   ]]

conn = sqlite3.connect('so.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE data
             (name text, age int, occupation text)''')
c.executemany('INSERT INTO data VALUES (?,?,?)', a)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

---

**Now searching in database:**

```
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('so.db')
>>> c = conn.cursor()
```

Number of `rows`:

```
>>> c.execute('''select count(*) from data''').next()
(4,)
```

Searching by `name`:

```
>>> c.execute('''select * from data where name="Paul"''').fetchall()
[(u'Paul', 22, u'Car Dealer')]
>>> c.execute('''select * from data where name="qwerty"''').fetchall()
[]
```

Searching by `age`:

```
>>> c.execute('''select * from data where age="66"''').fetchall()
[(u'Mark', 66, u'Retired')]
```

Searching by `occupation`:

```
>>> c.execute('''select * from data where occupation="Engineer"''').fetchall()
[]
>>> c.execute('''select * from data where occupation="Doctor"''').fetchall()
[(u'Nick', 30, u'Doctor')]
```

---

Use `next` if you want just `True` and `False` as output:

```
>>> bool(next(c.execute('''select * from data where age=36'''), 0))
False
>>> bool(next(c.execute('''select * from data where age=66'''), 0))
True
```

`c.fetchall()` will return all matching rows.

Comment: that could work, but there's ways for this to work without making a new database, so what's the reason to do it this way? you gave me some ideas, so thanks anyway!

Comment: @Nickl You can do that using lists, but those solutions are not efficient. Except `len()`, `any`, `generator expr`, `LC`  all of them are `O(N)` methods. For large items those methods won't scale.